# Comment Box like Twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, twitter, textfield

What I am trying to achieve is something like comment box on Twitter web site. I want to set a perfect regular expression which can include URL format like htttp://www.abc.com, abc.com, http://abc.com and www.abc.com. This should reduce only 20 characters from total text field limit of 140 characters. After 140 characters user should not allowed to type in.

I have find a good option from github but it does not have all these functionality and I am trying to fix it but still there is no success. Here I have given same link for your reference. 
http://jsfiddle.net/FUADn/1/

What still not working for me is:

1) Not able to track urls like: "abc.com", "www.abc.com" and "http://abc.com"

2) Not able to restrict typing after 140 characters, It continues typing and shows text in red color

Can any of you help me with this please

Comment: "I am trying to fix it but still there is no success" - what exactly is wrong and what do you need help with?

Comment: Edited my comment, sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

About the first question you can try a regular expression like this one:

```
((http|https):\/\/)?(www\.)?([A-Za-z0-9$_.+!*\(\),;/?:@&~=-])+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,})?(\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4})
```

I am not sure if it will be enough for your case, but you can give it a try.

As for the second question you can use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). For example:

```js
$("#post-msg").keypress(function (e) {
    var a=$("#post-msg").val().length; 

    if (a > 140) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    // ...
}
```